# How to remove dots below crosshair in minecraft 1.8.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There are dots below the crosshair in Minecraft 1.8.9 (Forge + optifine) as below :
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzs1G.png)
Is there some way I can disable them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dots are probably there because of one of the mods. Check your mods, and if you figured out what is causing the dots, then you may or may not be able to config the options in Mod Options or the config file.

Answer (score 1):

The dots are because it is a 1.9+ combat server, and you are in version 1.8.9. there is no texture for the attack cooldown in versions below 1.9, so it displays dots instead.